# What is the meaning of pre-compiled in AOT (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, aot, angular-aot

I am going through the Angular documentation for AOT. I came across the word **pre-compiled**, but I'm unable to understand the meaning of it.

The line in the Angular documentation is:

> With AOT, the browser downloads a pre-compiled version of the application.

Link to documentation is https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just-in-Time (JIT), which compiles your app in the browser at runtime.
>   Ahead-of-Time (AOT), which compiles your app at build time.

The word **pre-compiled** means it already complied i.e  your Angular HTML and TypeScript code compiled into efficient JavaScript code during the build phase itself  before delivered and being run in the browser.